# JavaScript put Image data on top of canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have the following code which creates a rectangle as shown in the image below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>
  <p id='one'></p>

  <script>

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40)
    var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 16) {
      imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
      imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
      imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
      imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    // ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

When I make sure that the image data is added by not commenting `ctx.putImageData` , I get only the image data like the picture shown below:

[image]

---

How do I make sure that the image is created on top of the black rectangle in the sense that in the white spaces between the red lines?
I want to be able to see the black rectangle. I tried changing the alpha channel but that did not do anything.

Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`putImageData` will replace the targeted pixels with the ones contained in your ImageData, whatever they are.
This means that if your ImageData contains transparent pixels, these transparent pixels will be there once you put the ImageData on your canvas.

There are several ways to accomplish what you want though.

The one requiring the less code change, is to make your pixel manipulation from the current state of your context. By calling [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) instead of `createImageData`, you will have an ImageData which contains the currently drawn pixels in the area you selected.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
// get the current pixels at (x, y, width, height)
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(10, 10, 100, 100);
var i;
// and do the pixel manip over these pixels
for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 16) {
  imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
  imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

The main caveat is that `getImageData` is slower and requires more memory than `createImageData`, so if you are gonna do it every frame in an animation, it may not be suitable.

An other solution in this case (animation), is to use a second off-screen canvas, on which you will draw once your ImageData, an then draw this off-screen canvas on the main one using `drawImage`.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
var gridImage = generateGrid(100, 100);

var x = 0;
anim();

/* 
  Makes your pixel manip on an off-screen canvas
  Returns the off-screen canvas
*/
function generateGrid(width, height){
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  var off_ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imgData = off_ctx.createImageData(width, height);
  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 16) {
    imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
    imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
    imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
  }
  off_ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0,0);
  return canvas;
}
function anim(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
  x = (x + 1) % (c.width + 100);
  ctx.fillRect(x, 20, 40, 40);
  // and here you draw your generated canvas
  ctx.drawImage(gridImage, x - 10, 0);
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

You could also refactor your code in order to make your *normal* drawings (here `fillRect`) **after** you did draw the ImageData, but **behind** current drawings, thanks to the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property of your context:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// do first your pixel manip
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 16) {
  imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
  imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);

// change the gCO to draw behind current non-transparent pixels
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
// now make your normal drawings
ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
// reset the gCO
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

And finally, if you target only [**next-gen browsers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap#Browser_compatibility), then you could make use of the [ImageBitmap object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap), which will produce the same result as the off-screen canvas, in less lines of code:

```js
(async () => {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  var gridImage = await generateGrid(100, 100);
  var x = 0;
  anim();

  /* 
    Makes your pixel manip on an empty ImageData
    Returns an Promise resolving to an ImageBitmap
  */
  function generateGrid(width, height) {
    var imgData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 16) {
      imgData.data[i + 0] = 255;
      imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
      imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
      imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
    }
    return createImageBitmap(imgData);
  }

  function anim() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    x = (x + 1) % (c.width + 100);
    ctx.fillRect(x, 20, 40, 40);
    // and here you draw your generated canvas
    ctx.drawImage(gridImage, x - 10, 0);
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  }
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make it work with you exact code but when I tried with 2 images overlapping I managed to make them overlap.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
<p id = 'one'></p>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);
 var i;
for (i = 0; i < img.data.length; i += 6) {
  img.data[i+0] = 255;
  img.data[i+1] = 0;
  img.data[i+2] = 0;
  img.data[i+3] = 255;
}
var img2 = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < img2.data.length; i += 20) {
  img2.data[i+0] = 0;
  img2.data[i+1] = 255;
  img2.data[i+2] = 0;
  img2.data[i+3] = 255;
}
  var pixels = 4*100*100;
  var imgData1 = img.data;
  var imgData2 = img2.data;
  while (pixels--){
    imgData1[pixels] = imgData1[pixels] * 0.5 + imgData2[pixels] *0.5;
  }
  img.data = imgData1;
ctx.putImageData(img, 10, 0);

</script>
```