# slide pixels one space to the left using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to slide the pixel of an image left, as if the image was one single array and I move the array 1 position left with wrap around.

i.e. if it was a 4x4 image

1 2 3 4

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12

13 14 15 16

as a single array it would become
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

which is then shifted

2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 1

which results in an image

2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9

10 11 12 13

14 15 16 1

I think I'm moving/addressing the array incorrectly, but can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="picture" src="img_the_scream.jpg" width="220" height="277">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="277" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
function rotateLeft(arr){
    let first = arr.shift();
    arr.push(first);
    return arr;
}

document.getElementById("picture").onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("picture");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // move pixels
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i] =  rotateLeft(imgData.data[i]);    //R
    imgData.data[i+1] = rotateLeft(imgData.data[i+1]); //G
    imgData.data[i+2] = rotateLeft(imgData.data[i+2]); //B
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255; //A
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

even if I directly modify the array, it shifts the entire image to the left, not sliding the pixels to 'wrap around' onto the next line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="picture" src="img_the_scream.jpg" width="220" height="277">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="277" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

document.getElementById("picture").onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("picture");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  // move pixels
  var i;
  offset=10;
  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i] =  (imgData.data[i+4*offset]);
    imgData.data[i+1] = (imgData.data[i+1+4*offset]);
    imgData.data[i+2] = (imgData.data[i+2+4*offset]);
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what kind of result you're trying to get, but I ran your code and
It seems that imgData.data is a one dimensional array.
but you're treating it as a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: I'm trying to shift each pixel left, as if it is a 1 dimensional array, think of ROT 13, but for images

Comment: Just to be clear, you really do want the whole image to be treated as one array, so it will gradually stop looking anything like the original image - is that right? (As opposed to moving the image rows each one pixel to the left, and then what was the first pixel in the row going to the end of the row)?

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in your browser's dev tools inspect factility console? You seem to be treating a number (R or G or B) as an array.

Comment: @A Haworth, yes, to give it a staircase like effect, so the image is distorted and does not look like the original at all.

Comment: @A Haworth no errors in the console. It is the modification of the array that is the issue...I'm just not groking the correct way to modify the array

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="picture" src="test1.jpeg" width="220" height="277">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="277" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>



</body>
<script>
function rotateLeft(arr){
  console.log(arr);
    let first = arr.shift();
    arr.push(first);
    return arr;
}

document.getElementById("picture").onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("picture");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  offset=10;
  for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 16) {
    imgData.data[i] =  (imgData.data[i+4*offset]);
    imgData.data[i+1] = (imgData.data[i+1+4*offset]);
    imgData.data[i+2] = (imgData.data[i+2+4*offset]);
    imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
};
</script>
</html
```

[image]

Comment: @Daz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48858220/javascript-put-image-data-on-top-of-canvas  I found a similar problem in stackoverflow, hope it can help you

Comment: @AmelloAster close, but it moves every 16th line by the same amount, not every line.  It should be like ROT, where you shift the pixels over by one then reassemble the image. Each line should be shifted, so that you get a staircase effect.

Comment: @Daz https://codepen.io/pizza3/pen/YavqYN You can look at this, I do not know if it is the effect you expect

Comment: sadly, no. See my original description, all pixel should be shifted to the left, if the go off the edge, they wrap up to the next line. Its easier to think of it as 1 d array, shift all the pixels, then reassemble it back to an image.